# React.js tic-tac-toe. Does `key` really work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the modified version of react tic-tac-toe , [CodePen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOYojw?editors=0010)

I've added time to the move description (only to see *when* `li` was rendered):

```
<li key={move}>
  <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc + ' ' + +new Date()}</button>
</li>
```

**Expected result:** each list item has different time, since `li`'s have `key`'s they don't get re-rendered on each move.
**What really happens:** each time a move is made time on each `li` changes (each `li` is rendered).

`Go to game start 1512330036500
Go to move #1 1512330036500
Go to move #2 1512330036500
Go to move #3 1512330036500
Go to move #4 1512330036500
Go to move #5 1512330036500`

What's wrong with my understanding of how it should behave?
Is there a way to make it work as I expect it to?

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood, the inclusion of the Date threw me off. But no, you don't want to use `move` as `key` since it just equates to the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `key` prop, React knows how to match an element inside a loop during the update phase, so that it doesn't re-render it if it's not necessary. Since `history.map` returns a different array every time, there would be no way for React to know how to match elements without a `key`. However, this doesn't mean that the component won't ever be re-rendered.

In your example, React is re-rendering your `li` because you are changing the `li`'s `children` prop by using a `new Date()` on each iteration.

You can achieve what you are trying to do just by adding the timestamp to `history`, into the state: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXqEqb

Comment: seems legit tho